# How to fix error code 0*0000007b

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bsod

I get the 0*0000007B BSOD error message (which allegedly is a compatibility problem) when trying to install XP with SP2 on my newly partitioned NTF formatted brand new HDD with Windows 7 on the first partition. This is on a Sony Vaio all-in-one which is 10 years old and works perfectly.

I've found no answers to remove this problem.

ACHI/IDE is not on my AMI BIOS. I can't load drivers if XP is not installed, XP mode in 7 and 10 in my opinion is rubbish, the free download in wiki answers is an advertising ploy, is there anyone out there who can help me please? :)

Comment: We need more info about when exactly the error arrives, but if the problem is missing drivers then you may need to slipstream them into the boot media. But I counsel against using XP - if the device supports Windows 10, then you may use Hyper-V to construct an XP virtual machine that will work, but you shouldn't use XP for browsing or installing occasional applications, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Can XP be installed on anything but the first partition of the first disk?  Just asking, I touch Windoze as rarely as possible.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: Yes.

Comment: It will not install on a clean formatted Hard Drive. XP is only used for an offline application. Thanks for the edit Twisty and by the way, you left no valuable solution.

Comment: What "free download in wiki answers" are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

So, your situation is:

- XP does not support AHCI mode out of the box.
- As you've found, you'd have to install it without AHCI, then install the AHCI driver and change the disk controller mode in the firmware.
- but apparently your Sony's firmware doesn't offer the option to run the disk controller in "IDE" mode
- So your Vaio is probably stuck in AHCI mode. ie incompatible with XP out of the box.

What should work is to make a new XP install CD with the driver you need  "slipstreamed" into it. You can use the free "nlite" tool for this.

To be certain of what chipset you have, boot an existing win7 or win10 install, open device manager, browse to the disk controller, right-click on it, "Details" tab, property "Hardware IDs". You will see a series of strings of this form:

PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_8D62&SUBSYS_86001043

In this case you would Google for

ven 8086 dev 8d62

By perusing the search results you can find out which chipset you have, and thereby which AHCI driver you need.

In this case vendor 8086 (that's Intel), device 8d62 is an "Intel(R) C600+/C220+ series chipset SATA AHCI" driver. C600 and C220 being chipset series from Intel. (The disk controller is part of your chipset.) Now you would in this case google for

site:intel.com "Intel(R) C600+/C220+ series chipset SATA AHCI"

and you would find the downloadable driver. (This particular driver wasn't built for XP so it's not really applicable here... but that's the system I have running right now.)

Now read the instructions here: https://www.wikihow.com/Slipstream-Your-SATA-Drivers-Into-a-Windows-XP-Installation-CD-Using-nLite to find out how to download and use the "nlite" tool to make a new installation CD with the drivers you need integrated.

If you can provide the hardware ID of your disk controller, I could try to provide more specific instructions.

(This sort of thing is why I only buy laptops with fully-featured firmware settings. IME Sony has commonly "simplified" their machines too much in this and other ways.)

Comment: All sorted. Because the pc has a limited bios I've installed Win 7 pro with XP mode and the virtual drive from MS site. This saves all the other hassle. Thank you for your help. Best Regards, Dave.